# Install persistent, running Kubuntu on USB drive from Windows without installing on system drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation, kubuntu

I am new to Linux and am having trouble installing Kubuntu on a USB drive. I’m on Windows, and I used Rufus and Universal USB installer from pendrivelinux.com to install ISOs I downloaded but I only get the Live CD version of Kubuntu. I want to install a running, usable copy of Kubuntu on my USB with persistence – I don’t want to install from the USB.

I have tried Kubuntu from here - https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/  and Ubuntu from here - https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. When I boot unto either of them, I get the option to Try or Install. I select the Install option and it tells me I can install on my system drive - I don’t want that: I want to install a running Linux installation from my USB. How can I do that?

Comment: Does a virtual machine count as cheating?

Comment: I'm trying to run Linux right from the USB drive, as in booting into the OS from the USB drive. I also tried running a virtualbox to try to install on a separate USB drive but the VM couldn't connect to the new USB drive.

Comment: Have you enabled passthrough of the USB drive to VM? You have to select devices to passthrough one by one.

Comment: I got USB working and booted the VM into the Kubuntu ISO; I selected to install and selected the USB  drive to install on. It takes a very long time and installation finishes but my USB drive is empty afterwards. I try to boot into it, and it doesn't boot using the USB drive. I tried with Kubuntu and Ubuntu - I think the installer isn't partitioning my drive properly or not formatting it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Please ask a separate question. Include a screenshot from GParted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 3 years old, but its still coming up highly ranked in a google or duckduckgo search.

For anyone wanting to achieve this post 2024, either Ventoy or Universal USB installer is software you may want to look at.

It allows for a USB drive to hold multiple operating systems with persistent memory for each. I have a couple of Ventoy USB sticks which have Debian, Ubuntu and Arch based OS's on each and it behaves exactly the way you think it would, boot from the USB, then it presents a grub menu to pick your OS and from there you would think it's native to the machines hard drive.

I hope this helps any wary net crawler who stumbles on this post.

Take care and stay root.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).